# Подскажите актуальные источники с информацией о работе с JNI в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, jni

2 день пытаюсь собрать проект с JNI вставкой, ни в какую не хочет собираться проект, пишет, что нету файла и всё тут.
Пытался всё сделать и по официальным и неофициальным источникам.
Суть такова, сначала я скачал NDK с [офф источника](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/ndk/downloads/index.html). Далее распаковал и прописал путь к NDK в **LocalProerties**, далее использовал **javah**, который мне выплюнул нужный мне файл **.h** и автоматом добавил его в каталог **c**, потом создал ещё файл который инклудил созданный, и там уже описал работу функции. Также добавил ещё 1 пустой **.c** (в источниках пишут, что есть баги на Windows, если используется только 1 исполняемый файл), потом в **build.gradle** добавил данные строки

```
ndk{
   moduleName "MyLib"
}
```

Как я понял, это даёт понять сборщику, что нужно создать модуль с именем MyLib из тех фалов, что будут лежать в каталоге **c**, вроде всё норм (насколько я знаю) и даже если нажать **Make Project**, то всё тоже гуд, но как только нажимаю **Run** всё это дело крашится через некоторое время и возвращает мне это

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    D:\android-ndk-r10e\ndk-build.cmd NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\miroshnichenko\Downloads\android-serialport-api-master\android-serialport-api-master\TestNDKProject\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\Android.mk APP_PLATFORM=android-22 NDK_OUT=C:\Users\miroshnichenko\Downloads\android-serialport-api-master\android-serialport-api-master\TestNDKProject\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\miroshnichenko\Downloads\android-serialport-api-master\android-serialport-api-master\TestNDKProject\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\lib APP_STL=gnustl_shared APP_ABI=all
Error Code:
    2
Output:
    C:\Users\miroshnichenko\Downloads\android-serialport-api-master\android-serialport-api-master\TestNDKProject\app\src\main\jni\main.c:8:3: fatal error: opening dependency file C:\Users\miroshnichenko\Downloads\android-serialport-api-master\android-serialport-api-master\TestNDKProject\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/MyLib/C_\Users\miroshnichenko\Downloads\android-serialport-api-master\android-serialport-api-master\TestNDKProject\app\src\main\jni\main.o.d: No such file or directory
       }
       ^
    compilation terminated.
    make.exe: *** [C:\Users\miroshnichenko\Downloads\android-serialport-api-master\android-serialport-api-master\TestNDKProject\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/MyLib/C_\Users\miroshnichenko\Downloads\android-serialport-api-master\android-serialport-api-master\TestNDKProject\app\src\main\jni\main.o] Error 1
```

Как я отсюда понял, ошибка в том, что не может найти файл **main.o.d**, я вообще хз, что это за файл, могу лишь предположить, что Android Studio - редиска и не закомпилила **.so** файл. очень прошу помочь в этой беде ибо всё уже перепробовал

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, что Android Studio поддерживает NDK. По крайней мере полгода назад он не поддерживал. Сейчас, он [якобы поддерживает](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudiowithandroidndkpreviewsupportavailable), но сноска *preview* как бы говорит сама за себя.

Я лично работал с NDK через студию посредством старого доброго ANT'а, запускал ANT скриптом сборку `*.so` библиотек, которые уже цеплялись студией.

Comment: НУ, я бы даже поспорил, про пол года назад, т.к. есть статься на хабре аж за 2013 год, там инструкция, и даже видео есть от Intel, но по их методике вот такая ошибка, к тому же я заметил, что там довольно другая структура проекта, видимо версия Android Studio старенькая. Ссылка на статью http://habrahabr.ru/company/intel/blog/216353/

Comment: По поводу поддержки, то и до сих пор необходимо скачивать NDK пакет отдельно и никаких доп. иконок в Android Studio для этого нету

Comment: Вообще я прочитал, что в Gradle довольно убогая сборка для JNI, слишком много ограничений, нашёл статью, где описано для другой NDK сборки, так там описана более гибкая система сборки проекта в Gradle. под более гибкой я понимаю, описание сборки, как в Ant

Answer (score 1):

Удалось мне таки осилить **JNI** в **Android Studio** с использованием **Gradle**.
Для того, чтобы всё сработало необходимо скачать самую актуальную версию Android Studio (На данный момент, это 1.4), далее необходимо скачать **Gradle** версии 2.5 (Очень важно!!! Необходимо ставить 2.5, не ниже и не выше, т.к. Android Studio тупит с другими). Далее нужно будет поковыряться с Gradle скриптами по [вот этой инструкции](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental). Там всё грамотно описано для использования экспериментального грэдла. Создавать C/C++ native файлы необходимо через терминал функцией **javah** (Очень важно!!! Выполнять **javah** нужно в папке приложения ..src\main, иначе **.so** не будет собираться). Если вы всё сделаете верно, то всё заработает, но для более детального разбирательства можно скачать "**Hallo Jni**" сэмпл в **Android Studio**.
И главное не забыть указать нахождение NDK в locale.properties (отдельный файл) в Gradle скрипте.

Официально есть жалобы на отсутствие важных библиотек в NDK для Android, поэтому есть другая сборка, которая содержит всё нужно и даже больше, в том числе библиотека **[Boost](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost)**, более подробно [здесь](https://www.crystax.net/ru/blog/3).
Надеюсь я смог этим всем помочь тем, кто также не знал, как использовать **JNI** в **Android Studio**